# python equivalent of vlookup in a dataframe

Tags: python

I have a df

```
df = {'a1': [2, 4, 7, 5, 6],
     'a2': [A, B, C, D, A],
     'a3': [4, 3, 2, 8, 7],
     'x1': [2, 2, 4, 6, 4],
     'x2': [2, 2, 2, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=range(0,5))
```

and a dict:

```
cost={}
cost['A']=0.2
cost['B']=0.1
cost['C']=0.3
cost['D']=0.5
```

I wish to add an additional column 'cost' to my df, such that the cost column is the relvant cost based on the relevant letter, found in col a2.

desired output would be a df as such: (if I manually wrote it out!)

```
df = {'a1': [2, 4, 7, 5, 6],
     'a2': [A, B, C, D, A],
     'a3': [4, 3, 2, 8, 7],
     'x1': [2, 2, 4, 6, 4],
     'x2': [2, 2, 2, 6, 7],
     'cost': [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2]}
```

My inefficient way thus far is:

```
df['cost']=df['a2']
for i in range(0,len(df.index),1):
    df['cost'][i]=cost[df['cost'][i]]
```

does someone know how to do this without a loop?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your `df` and `cost`.

```
df['cost'] = df['a2'].apply(cost.get)
```

This probably isn't *that* much faster than a `for` loop, perhaps there are better ways. 
Output:

```
   a1 a2  a3  x1  x2  cost
0   2  A   4   2   2   0.2
1   4  B   3   2   2   0.1
2   7  C   2   4   2   0.3
3   5  D   8   6   6   0.5
4   6  A   7   4   7   0.2
```